# Can't set a hotword with deepspeech

Tags: mozilla-deepspeech

I tried to set my hotword for deepspeech on my raspberry pi and got a really long error when I sent this in terminal:

python3 /home/pi/DeepSpeech_RaspberryPi4_Hotword/mic_streaming.py --keywords jarvis

**Error**
[image: The error. I tried to post it in text but it kept saying the code isn't formatted correctly. I don't know if an error counts as code so i'm just sending a screenshot.]

I don't know how to fix this and didn't find anything anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these errors are not related to `DeepSpeech`, they're related to `ALSA`, which is the sound subsystem for Linux. By the looks of the error, your system is having trouble accessing the microphone.

I would recommend running several `ALSA` tests, such as;

`arecord -l`

This should give you a list of recording devices that are detected, such as:

```
$ arecord -l


**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC294 Analog [ALC294 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

If this is not what you expected, you can use the command `alsamixer` to select another sound card and/or microphone.

Answer (score 0):

hi this script writen by AIWintermuteAI at github and he is using respeaker 4 mic array card with raspberry pi. u need to have this attached to your raspberry pi or need to change script according to your mic. i'm not an expert but i'll try to test this script with my usb webcam mic.i'll update result here